# Shell aborts while using threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, scheduling

I've created a program that will read data from a file inputted by the user, and use the shortest remaining time first (SRTF) scheduling to calculate average waiting and turnaround time. I've written a parent program that creates a thread, which then executes the scheduling program. The SRTF code works fine and calculates the values correctly as I have tested it.

The code I have written as follows works perfectly without any issues.

Example file

```
0 1 2
1 3 1
2 3 2
```

Main method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* SRTF (void* arg);

int main()
{
    pthread_t threadB;
    pthread_create(&threadB,NULL,SRTF,NULL);
    pthread_join(threadB,NULL);
}
```

SRTF code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* SRTF (void* arg)
{   
    float totalWait = 0.0;
    float totalTurn = 0.0;
    int totalBurst = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    int numProcess = 0;
    int AT[10], BT[10], PT[10], WT[10],PR[100],FT[10];
    int swap; 
    int small; 
    char fileName[10];

    FILE* fp; 
    char line[10];

    printf("SRTF simulation\n");

    printf("Enter filename\n");
    scanf("%s",fileName);

    fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    
    while (fgets(line,10,fp) != NULL)
    {
        numProcess++;
    }
    rewind(fp);

    i=0;
    while(i<numProcess)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&AT[i],&BT[i],&PT[i]);
        totalBurst += BT[i];
        WT[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }

    /*ordering the array*/
    for (i=0; i<numProcess; i++)
    {
        /*next index*/
        for (j=i+1; j<numProcess; j++)
        {
            if(AT[i] > AT[j])
            {    
                swap = AT[i];
                AT[i] = AT[j];
                AT[j] = swap; 
                swap = BT[i];
                BT[i] = BT[j];
                BT[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<totalBurst; i++)
    {
        small = 3200;
        for (j=0; j<numProcess; j++)
        {
            if ((BT[j] != 0) && (AT[j] <=i) && (BT[j]<small))
            {   
                small = BT[j];
                k = j;
            }
        }   
        
        BT[k]--;
        PR[i] = k;
    }

    for (i=0; i<totalBurst; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<numProcess; j++)
        {
            if (PR[i] == j)
            {
                FT[j] = i;
                WT[j]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<numProcess; i++)
    {
        printf("\nProcess : %d\tFinish Time : %d\tTurnaround Time : %d\tWaiting Time : %d\tArrival Time : %d",i+1,FT[i]+1,(FT[i] - AT[i])+1,(((FT[i]+1)-WT[i])-AT[i]),AT[i]);
        totalWait = totalWait + (((FT[i] + 1) - WT[i]) - AT[i]);
        totalTurn = totalTurn + ((FT[i] - AT[i]) + 1);
    }

    printf("\nAverage waiting time : %f\nAverage turnaround time : %f",totalWait/numProcess,totalTurn/numProcess);

    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}
```

However what I would like, is for the parent (main) process to prompt the user for the filename, which will then pass the filename to SRTF and continue on, rather than the actual filename prompt occurring within the SRTF method. I made the following changes to my code:

Main

```
int main()
{
    char fileName[10];
    pthread_t threadB;
    
    printf("Enter the filename\n");
    scanf("%s",fileName);

    pthread_create(&threadB,NULL,SRTF,fileName);
    pthread_join(threadB,NULL);
}
```

SRTF

```
void* SRTF (void* arg)
{   
    float totalWait = 0.0;
    float totalTurn = 0.0;
    int totalBurst = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    int numProcess = 0;
    int AT[10], BT[10], PT[10], WT[10],PR[100],FT[10];
    int swap; 
    int small; 
    char* fileName;

    FILE* fp; 
    char line[10];

    printf("SRTF simulation\n");
    fileName = (char*)arg;

    fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
//rest of code is same as previous
```

When I try to do this, I can see that the file is read without any errors, as the correct values for average turnaround and waiting time is calculated. The entire code runs, but at the very end zsh abort is shown and the program terminates. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?
thanks

Comment: There should be a checklist on all stackoverflow c questions imo. Have you tried valgrind, does gdb say anything enlightening, have you tried thread sanitizers? Do you have any outstanding compiler warnings?

Comment: `scanf("%s",fileName);` where `fileName` can only hold a 9 character long name seems like an obvious potential issue.  *Never* use `%s` in scanf.  Always use a maximum width.  (In this case `"%9s"`).  As a simple first step, increase the size and use`char fileName[PATH_MAX]`.